# How to create a Github staging branch for React app

Tags: reactjs, git, github

I've tried searching for solutions but I'm struggling with how to configure my React app to temporarily push to a staging branch while I make some changes and merge with the gh-pages one created after initially setting up the repo with React.

Am I right in thinking I need to first create the branch and then just switch to it using git checkout?

I tried creating a branch in the terminal but it doesn't appear on my github account

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the branch from GitHub. Git terminal will create only local branch in your machine. So create the branch on GitHub, switch to the same branch name and push your changes. You can follow below guide for a quick tutorial if you want to do everything from terminal itself:

https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/git/how-to-create-a-remote-branch-in-git.html#pushing-a-local-branch-to-remote-9

Comment: After making it on GithHub should I then do: git fetch > git checkout <mynewbranch>? thanks for your help